# Building a html table with data from localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, css

1. No table on the side
2. in console we get "404 resource not found"
3. Uncaught ReferenceError: Employee1 is not defined at Employee.js:19

```
    //Classes defined
class Employee {
constructor(employee_username, password, department, yy, email, level) {
    this.employee_user = employee_username;
    this.password = password;
    this.department = department;
    this.email = email;
    this.skills = [];
    this.level = level;
}
// function: Pushses new skill, in "Skills" array
addNewSkill(skill){
        this.skills.push(skill);
}
}
// function: Deletes from "skills" array

//Employee Database "Localstorage"
   if(localStorage.getItem('Employee') == null) {
        var employeeList = [];
       employeeList.push (new Employee1("Simon", 1234, "HR", 1999, "123@mail.dk", '1'));
       employeeList.push (new Employee2("Mads", 12345,"IT", 1999,  "1234@email.com", '1'));
       employeeList.push (new Employee3("Jessica", 54321, "Sales",1998, "Mail2@mail.dk",'1'));
       employeeList.push (new Employee4("Benjamin", 4321,"IT", 1997, "blabla@mail.dk", '1'));

       var employeeListString = JSON.stringify(employeeList)
       localStorage.setItem('Employee', employeeListString)
   } else {
       var employeeList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Employee'))
   }

    function buildTable(data) {
        let table = document.createElement("table");
        let fields = Object.keys(data[0]);
        let headRow = document.createElement("tr");
        fields.forEach(function(field) {
            let headCell = document.createElement("th");
            headCell.textContent = field;
            headRow.appendChild(headCell);
        });
        table.appendChild(headRow);
        data.forEach(function(object) {
            let row = document.createElement("tr");
            fields.forEach(function(field) {
                let cell = document.createElement("td");
                cell.textContent = object[field];
                if (typeof object[field] == "number") {
                    cell.style.textAlign = "right";
                }
                row.appendChild(cell);
            });
            table.appendChild(row);
        });
return table;
    }
    document.querySelector(Employees)
        .appendChild(buildTable(employeeList));

   //var employeeOutput = document.getElementsByClassName(Employee)
    //employeeOutput.innerHTML = Employee;




   // lav en HTML side med <div id="employees"> ligesom mountains

    // indsæt buildTable function i javascript

    // Kald document.querySelector for employees og funktionen buildTable(employeeList) i stedet for buildTable(MOUNTAINS)

    // Læs kapitel 14 i bogen om DOM
```

Comment: Please always post your relevant code right here in your question as opposed to having us have to go out and see it elsewhere.

Comment: we can't detect the errors unless we see the code first, so post some related code and be specific

Comment: PLEASE! Don't post pictures of your code. Post the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first:

1. You created a class **Employee** and you are trying to instantiate it as **Employee1**, **Employee2** and **Employee3**, which leads to the error in the specified line.
2. Document.querySelector with **Employees** instead of a selector string
3. You are not creating and inserting the elements in **thead** and **tbody**

Here a snippet of your code working with the proper changes:

```js
//Classes defined

class Employee {
  constructor(employee_username, password, department, yy, email, level) {
    this.employee_user = employee_username;
    this.password = password;
    this.department = department;
    this.email = email;
    this.skills = [];
    this.level = level;
  }
  
  // function: Pushses new skill, in "Skills" array
  addNewSkill(skill){
    this.skills.push(skill);
  }
}

//Employee Database "Localstorage"
if(localStorage.getItem('Employee') == null) {
   var employeeList = [];
   employeeList.push (new Employee("Simon", 1234, "HR", 1999, "123@mail.dk", '1'));
   employeeList.push (new Employee("Mads", 12345,"IT", 1999,  "1234@email.com", '1'));
   employeeList.push (new Employee("Jessica", 54321, "Sales",1998, "Mail2@mail.dk",'1'));
   employeeList.push (new Employee("Benjamin", 4321,"IT", 1997, "blabla@mail.dk", '1'));

   var employeeListString = JSON.stringify(employeeList)
   localStorage.setItem('Employee', employeeListString)
} else {
   var employeeList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Employee'))
}

function buildTable(data) {
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  
  // Create table head and body
  table.appendChild(document.createElement('thead'));
  table.appendChild(document.createElement('tbody'));
  
  let fields = Object.keys(data[0]);
  let headRow = document.createElement("tr");
  fields.forEach(function(field) {
      let headCell = document.createElement("th");
      headCell.textContent = field;
      headRow.appendChild(headCell);
  });
  table.querySelector('thead').appendChild(headRow);
  data.forEach(function(object) {
      let row = document.createElement("tr");
      fields.forEach(function(field) {
          let cell = document.createElement("td");
          cell.textContent = object[field];
          if (typeof object[field] == "number") {
              cell.style.textAlign = "right";
          }
          row.appendChild(cell);
      });
      table.querySelector('tbody').appendChild(row);
  });
  return table;
}

document.querySelector('#employees').appendChild(buildTable(employeeList));
```

```html
<div id="employees"></div>
```

Notice that the snippet won't work because it's sandboxed and can't access **localStorage**, just try it on your computer and you should have this output:

[image: output sample]

Hope it helps :)

Comment: We tend not to answer poor questions that should be closed in the first place, because when we do answer, it just encourages more poor questions. It's great that you helped, but now others may feel that they can post questions that don't even have the code in it and still get an answer.

Comment: @ScottMarcus got it, in this scenario the ideal measure would be to comment what's wrong and downvote ?

Comment: Hey, first time poosting here. Im doing my best :) thx for the help @MatheusGomes

Comment: It depends on the rep of the OP. This is a new SO member, so I don't think down voting is right. But, a comment to to the OP (as some of us did) is certainly warranted. If the OP isn't new, then a down vote and a vote to close is warranted.

Comment: Actually i still get an error in my console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null at Employee.js:63" do you have any idea why? @MatheusGomes

Comment: @BenjaminNielsen you must have a DIV tag with id "employees" in your body and your script "Employee.js" must be referenced after it.

Comment: @BenjaminNielsen you could also make your code wait the page load entirely before executing (window.onload).

Answer (score 0):

json can't store classes just plain objects.

you need to use a replacer  function  - a parameter to JSON.stringify

the idea is something like this:

```js
function replacer(key, value) {
  // Filtering out properties
  if (instanceof value === Employee) {
    return {
              ...value
           };
  }
  return value;
}

JSON.stringify(foo, replacer);
```

more at
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

then on load

```js
function reviver(value){
  return new Employee(value)
}

var employes=[]
if(text)employes=JSON.parse(text).map(reviver)
```